# "password authentication didn't work" Can't get past login

Tags: partitioning, login, password, crash, authentication

So I installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 on my laptop (a legion 5 pro) using VirtualBox. While installing at the part where it asks if we want to Erase disk and install Ubuntu (the option selected) i proceeded to click next and i get this prompt saying ..

Write the changes to disks?

If you continue, the changes listed below will be written to the disk. Otherwise, you will be able to make further changes manually.

The partition tables of the following devices are changed:

SCSI3 (0,0,0,) (sda)

The following partitions are going to be formatted:

partition #2 of SCSI3 (something i don't remember)

partition #3 of SCSI3 (something i don't remember)

I found out through forums that this is normal and proceeded to click continue and the installation began... the installation took about 35 mins and then it asked for a restart and i clicked restart.

Then it asked to remove the boot disk and press enter. i made sure the iso file under devices virtualbox was unchecked and pressed enter. **Immediately i get a black screen with blue vertical lines and several red pixel patches (like a BSOD but worse crash screen).**
sometimes the install won't proceed further and might remain at a command prompt kinda screen with somthing related to recovery but no progress whatsoever.

but i got lucky now, although the 'BSOD but worse crash screen' appeared, somehow ubuntu managed to restart and got me to login. click on my username and enter my password but now i get a message saying "sorry password authentication didn't work, please try again". But the password I'm entering is correct!

I even tried to change my password through Grub, it didn't work. I'm able to change my password but the same issue persists even with the new password. (i also noticed that rw command used to change the password again changes back to ro after restarting or powering back on)

Comment: Sounds like the ISO used in the install may have been bad. Did you verify it? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

Comment: Just to confirm, this installation is in a virtual machine?

Comment: @OrganicMarble yes.... This is an install of Ubuntu on VirtualBox (VM)

Comment: @David don't you need to get into Ubuntu in order to proceed to check if the ISO's not corrupt?? I can't even get past login and the steps for verification installing a software which I'm not sure how to cuz this Ubuntu install is on a VM....

Comment: No you verify the ISO after you download it and before installing it.